# Circle CI API shows hidden value for environment vars in response, how to unhide or get full value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, circleci, circleci-workflows

I feed some env variables in circle CI project and using its API(https://circleci.com/docs/api/#list-environment-variables) trying to get values of env vars but it returns hidden values except the last 4 digits(xxxx4134). I want to list and fetch the values  to be utilized in my code, so how can I unhide it or have a way to get the proper values in response to be used in other parts of code?

Below is the code I tried in javascript that does return env vars values but hidden.

```
const options= {
        url: 'https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/projectName/envvar?circle-token={{apiToken}}',
        method: 'GET',
        json: true,
        resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    }
    request(options).then(response => { console.log('response=', response.body)
for (var count = 0; count < response.body.length; count++) {
            var item = response.body[count]
            if (item.name == 'C_ID') {
                const cId = item.value
            }
        })
```

Actual API call Response :

````
  "name" : "A_TOKEN",
  "value" : "xxxx7177"
}, {
  "name" : "C_ID",
  "value" : "xxxx51fa"
}]```

Upon using parsed json values, for instance of C_ID i.e; "xxxx51fa" in my other API calls results in error as it doesn't understand xxxx.

Any suggestions or help greatly appreciated.
````

Answer (score 0):

It appears requesting a single environment variable will return the whole value.

```
curl https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/:vcs-type/:username/:project/envvar/:name?circle-token=:token
```

where `:name` is the environment variable you desire.

Comment: thanks for the response but I quickly tried from a REST client tool and it seems even requesting a single env variable returns hidden value. 
```{
  "name" : "C_ID",
  "value" : "xxxx51fa"
}```

Comment: @daniel-a-white Even documentation says that it shows hidden values https://circleci.com/docs/api/#get-single-environment-variable

Comment: @SoC english is hard. i read it as the actual value. i'd contact circle ci

Comment: yea its quite contradictory as per what doc says. I reached out to Circle CI for this issue but it's weird that we can't actually read env vars then what's the purpose of having APIs when you cannot retrieve them.